# Архивация файлов в папке

Tags: c#

Как и чем заархивировать все файлы в папке?

Помогите пожалуйста с примером кода.

Только чтобы метод/библиотека была надежна, без всяких трудноуловимых багов, а то вот например [Баг в DotNetZip](http://shepeliev.blogspot.ru/2012/08/dotnetzip.html) или [кодировкой](http://svitter.ru/?p=898), даже и не знаю что использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С кодировкой все ормально в общем у SharpZipLib.

качаем библиотеку ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip с [официльного](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) сайта,

добавляем ссылку на дллку в проекте,

подключаем в using.

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using System.IO;
```

используем в коде:

**Создание архива**

где первый параметр - имя архива,
ToZip - путь до папки файлов,

третий параметр - включать или нет рекурсивный поиск файлов в папке

четвертый параметр -  fileFilter, основанный на регулярном выражении.

```
FastZip zip = new FastZip();
zip.CreateZip("my.zip","ToZip", true,null);
```

**Разархиварование**:

```
zip.ExtractZip("my.zip", "New", null);
```

"my.zip" - имя архива который нужно распаковать

"New" - папка куда нужно извлечь файлы архива, если её не существует она будет создана.

третий параметр -  fileFilter, основанный на регулярном выражении.